# jQuery appendTo ignoring last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm trying to append a copy of an element to the bottom of the parent element. It seems to append everything above the last element within the parent. [Live example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1as4mwx/)

```js
var count = 1;

$("#addBtn").click(function(){
  $('#trid1').clone().appendTo('table#exampleTable > tbody');
  count++;
  $('#trid1').last().prop('id', 'trid'+count);
  $('#trid'+count+' > th').html(count);
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table class="table" id="exampleTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">c1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="trid1" class="trclass">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addBtn">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change the id before appending the new element to the DOM.

Anyway I slightly refactored your code with that strategy in mind and better dealt with the current index every time you click the add button. The latest index gets saved in a data attribute in the table.

```js
$("#addBtn").click(function(){
  const latestIndex = $('#exampleTable').data('latest-index');
  let i = latestIndex+1;
  const newRow = $('#trid1').clone();
  newRow.prop('id', `trid${i}`);
  newRow.data('index', i);
  newRow.text(i);
  newRow.appendTo('table#exampleTable > tbody');
  $('#exampleTable').data('latest-index', i);
});
```

```css
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table" id="exampleTable" data-latest-index="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Rows</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="trid1" class="trclass">
      <th scope="row">1</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="addBtn">Add</button>
```